# File on server changed content but js still fetch old data

Tags: javascript, php, fetch

So i made js script which fetch content from file on my server.
I made php script to change file content, but when i change content my js script still get old data without changes but my file on server has been changed.
Js still get old data even when i refresh page.
What's wrong?

I tried to use fopen instead file_puts_contents but still js fetch old data.
I also tried make funcion async but nothing changed.

```
getListFromApi=()=>{
 let json = []
 $.ajax({
   url: 'https://mypage.pl/list.json',
   async: false,
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(data){
     json = data
   }
 })
 return json
}
```

Comment: Is mypage.pl caching files?

Answer (score 1):

The browser will cache its results, meaning if you make a request to the same URL multiple times, it'll just use the first result every time to make the fetch faster. It looks like you're using jQuery (correct?), in which case you can disable the caching by simply adding `cache: false` to your request object.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `cache: false` like IceMetalPunk answer, but you can add a query string too to your url, so the browser will not cache your response data. With a timestamp query string you will be sure in all environments

```
    getListFromApi=()=>{
     let json = []
     $.ajax({
       url: 'https://mypage.pl/list.json?nocache',
       async: false,
       cache: false,
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(data){
         json = data
       }
     })
     return json
    }
```